# Can my computer run Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

Just want to check if my computer can run Ubuntu. It is an old IBM ThinkPad, so here are the basic stats I could find:

```
IBM 28832ZU 
Processor Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor 1300MHz 
Processor Speed 1.27 GHz 
Memory (RAM) 2048 MB 
Operating System Microsoft Windows XP Professional 
Operating System Version 5.1.2600 
Intel Extreme Graphics 2M
```

And here is some info pulled from the graphics panel

NTEL(R) EXTREME GRAPHICS 2 FOR MOBILE REPORT

Report Date:        06/28/2013
Report Time[hr:mm:ss]:  17:53:20
Driver Version:     6.14.10.3943
Operating System:   Windows NT* 5.1.2600 Service Pack 2
Default Language:   English
DirectX* Version:   9.0
Physical Memory:    2038 MB
Min. Graphics Memory:   8 MB
Max. Graphics Memory:   64 MB
Graphics Memory in use: 7 MB
Processor:      x86 family 6 Model 9 Stepping 5
Processor Speed:    1296 MHZ
Device Revision:    2

- Output Devices Connected to Graphics Accelerator   *

Active Notebook Displays:1

Comment: I would try Kubuntu or Xubuntu. I've had a lot of luck with those on my previously XP machines since they have a smaller footprint and have more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu would be quite slow, if running at all, on your machine.

I would recommend trying Lubuntu, which is much leaner than Ubuntu and will work well with limited resources. Here is Lubuntu's homepage : http://www.lubuntu.net/

Answer (score 0):

I'll have you know:

- 512 MB RAM
- 12 Year old Toshiba Satelite
- No graphic card to mention

Other than when running 2 average programs at the same time, my laptop runs totally fine. Sure, it's slower than everyone elses, but with Ubuntu 12.04, this is the fastest I've ever been.

Answer (score -1):

I also have a low powered laptop with Lubuntu and all works great.
Lubuntu is a light weight UI.